# Remove duplicate links from my navigation Breadcrumb inside my Enterprise wiki site collection

Tags: 2013, css, master-page, custom-masterpage, breadcrumb

I am working on an Enterprise wiki site collection inside my sharepoint farm 2013 on-premises.
Now i am following this appraoch to show a Breadcrumb navigation link for my site collection [Link](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/08/sharepoint-2013-breadcrumb/). so i mainly added this code inside my master page under the `<div id="suiteBarRight">`, as follow:-

```
<div id="suiteBarRight">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="customBreadcrumb" runat="server">
<asp:SiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false" NodeStyle-

CssClass="breadcrumbNode" CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode" RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode" 

HideInteriorRootNodes="true" SkipLinkText=""/>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Now this worked for almost all the libraries and pages inside my enterprise wiki. which sound promising as it worked on the whole pages and susites. but i have noted this issue,  if i access a wiki page using its friendly-URL, where i will get this breadcrumb links:-

```
Business continuity Plan > BuisnesscontinuityPan > Home
```

here is a screenshot of the breadcrumb links:-

[image]

now the duplicate entry is the second link labeled `BuisnesscontinuityPlan`, where my site collection URL is `/sites/BuisnesscontinuityPlan`. now if i click on the first link labeled `Business continuity Plan`i will be redirected to the site home page which is fine. but if i clcik on the second link `BuisnesscontinuityPlan` i will be redirected to the Pages library. so now i want to remove the duplicate second link labeled `BuisnesscontinuityPlan`. so can anyone adivce if this is possible ? i am thinking of writing a custom css to do so? mainly to remove the `<a>` link inside the breadcrumb if it have the following label `BuisnesscontinuityPlan` and i need to remove the preceding ">" character as well.so can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to hide the element by just checking its `text`, then this jQuery code should work. I haven't tested it yet.

```
var $duplicateItem = $('#suitBarRight > span > span:nth-child(3)')
var duplicateText = $duplicateItem.text();
if (duplicateText == "BuisnesscontinuityPlan") {
    $duplicateItem.hide();  // this will hide element with text BuisnesscontinuityPlan
    $duplicateItem.next().hide();  // this will hide next ">" element
}
```

This code will just hide the element if text matches exactly to `BuisnesscontinuityPlan` and it must be third element in the DOM as shown on your screen.